# When should LVL limit functionality and when should there be two versions of an application, only one using LVL

Tags: android, android-lvl

I am preparing to add LVL (http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html) support to my application, but it appears that if a program has the capability to just use LVL to restrict functionality, then it may make sense to only have one version of a program, so if the user pays for the application, from within the app, then they could then have the full functionality.

This would just mean that for the free version it will be larger than needed, as it will also have all the code for the full version, but I am not seeing any other downside, and the positives is only one codebase to maintain and it would be easy to show the user what functionality they would have if the paid for it.

Is there any other reason that having one codebase would be a bad option?

Answer (score 0):

One drawback: All of the code will be present in the free version, making it marginally easier for crackers to get the full version of your app.

More importantly: I don't know how you'd effectively manage this in Android Market. You can't use the same package name for the free and paid versions of your app, so you have to produce two APKs anyway. And at that point, there's no point in doing an LVL check -- you already know which version the user has by looking at the package name.

(It's also worth noting that we recently enabled the licensing service for free apps -- so both APKs will return a LICENSED response if the user downloaded them from Market.)

And this point, you might as well just use a library project to re-use the free part of your app between the APKs.

Now, if you wanted to use in-app billing to accomplish all this, that's a valid strategy. But that's a different topic. :)